# How to proxy nginx request while keeping same url

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, servicestack

I'm using a self hosted service stack app with this configuration. So when I browse mysite.com/json/reply/mytestmethod I get redirected to mysite.com:1337/json/reply/mytestmethod. the app works fine except looking for help in removing the port 1337 part and make it appear to come from the mysite.com domain.

Cheers!

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mysite.com;

  root /var/www/mysite.com/html;
  index index.html;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:1337;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to strip the port you'll want to use a reverse proxy rather than redirect. In nginx a typical reverse proxy configuration looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
 }
```